# unable to send mail using php mail() codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $key = sha1(uniqid());
        $this->load->library('email', array('mailtype' => 'html'));
        $this->load->model('customerModel');
        $this->email->from('codeigniter.emailverify', 'emailverify');
        $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
        $this->email->subject('Confirm Your Account');

        $message = "Welcome Ayos Member";
        $message .="<p><a href='" . base_url() . "main/register_cust/$key'>CLICK HERE </a>TO COMFIRM YOUR ACCOUNT</p>";
        $this->email->message($message);

        if ($this->customerModel->account($key)) {
            if ($this->email->send()) {

                echo "<script>
                alert('Successfully Sent');
                window.location.href='register';
                </script>";

            } else {
              /*  echo "<script>
                alert('Failed to Sent');
                window.location.href='register';
                </script>";*/
                echo $this->email->print_debugger();
            }
        } else {
            echo "problem in database";
        }
    } else {
        $this->load->view('pages/include/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/register');
        $this->load->view('pages/include/footer');
    }
}
```

i have this code in email verification. it perfectly works in my pc it sent to the email and when i transfer my whole project in my laptop it doesnt sent to the email

Comment: btw i only used localhost

Comment: Is there any error showing . when you are sending mail.

Comment: Check Sendmail is configured or not.  Also check SMTP configurations used here...

Comment: @Shrikant Bhardwa in my pc there's no error but when i run it in my laptop i echo print_debugger

Comment: @ShrikantBhardwaj it says this Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Thu, 7 Apr 2016 08:53:34 +0200

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND i just copied the sendmail of my pc to my laptop so i will not config it manually in my laptop